# How to create Automated script in ubuntu using text editor

Tags: command-line

Where can I get the list or collections of syntax or command for terminal to manipulate my computer and or to create a simple application.

I am familiar with VBS script and DOS command to create some batches to automate my jobs in Windows, now I am sing Ubuntu 12.04 and my Question is... can I do the same thing using text editor in ubuntu  such as the gEdit?

Comment: You could start here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ and forget about VBS, it will only hinder you ;)

Comment: What sorts of jobs?

Comment: well, for instance I wanted to create directories, folder(s) then, putting files in it or review or get a certain file where a pop-up input box will appear to input the file name, I did it in Windows, but I am new in ubuntu and want to do the same stuff.

Comment: You'll probably want to use the `bash` scripting, with the `zenity` message box program. Both are installed by default. The link Rinzwind provided will get you started. To use `zenity`, simply look at the `man zenity` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search "unix cheat sheet" in google. You will get list of commands and its purpose.

There is something called as shell script in unix, similar to bat in windows. You can automate your work using shell script.

Use vim editor, it is a command line text editor.

Comment: Hey,thanks that's a Big help for me... I can start a scratch form that, thanks man!

Comment: Uhm... vim is a good editor. But it is **not** for the faint of heart. At least have this [cheat-sheet for vim](http://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html)